# Laravel - Session variable losses value on middleware

Tags: laravel, caching, middleware

I have a Provider which stablishes a session variable:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('selectedPlatform', function($app) {
            $sp = Session('platform', 0);
            try {
                $p = $sp == 0 ? new Platform : Platform::findOrFail($sp);
            } catch(ModelNotFoundException $error) {
                abort(404);
            }
            return $p;
        });
    }
```

When I use `app('selectedPlatform')` I get a correct Platform class model:

```
<select name="platformSelector" id="platformSelector" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Seleccione una plataforma</option>
    @foreach(\App\Models\Platform::all() as $platform)
        <option value="{{$platform->id}}" @if(app('selectedPlatform')->id == $platform->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $platform->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I am trying to make a Middleware in which I check if a platform was selected (just not equal 0), and, if not, I send a flash to the user.

My issue is that when I use `app('selectedPlatform')` on the middleware, the session var losses its value.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $selected = app('selectedPlatform');
    if ($selected instanceof Platform)) {
         FlashMessage::addInfo('You must select a platform', 'Unselected platform');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I did have try commenting the complete if, just leaving the first line `$selected = app('selectedPlatform')`with the same result. This ensures us that FlashMessage class is not the problema here.

According the documentation of the [laravel lifecycle](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/lifecycle) first the core loads the service container (includen Service Providers) and then loads the Middleware. In the middleware, If I write `dd($selected)`I get an instance of the Platform, so the var has correct data.

What am I missing? Maybe invoking session variables value in a middleware removes its value?

Comment: @Thomas can't understand you. In the middleware it has been resolved (checked with `dd()`), so why In the view the var is empty?

Comment: Man, see the code, the Middleware are calling the Singleton 'selectedPlatform that loads from the Provider the session var and instantiates a Platform object. If I `dd($selected) inside the middleware it HAS a correct instance of Platform, but 
 LATER the singleton returns an empty value in the VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage finally by myself (thanks @Thomas for deleting your helpful comments). Laravel middleware has 3 types:

- General
- Route
- Group

In this case I was using general middleware (affects every request in the project). The general middleware is loaded before Laravel loads the sessions vars. So it comes blank.